# Remove everything between specified characters including multi lines

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

I have a file with contents like so:

```
## this must go ##
## also
 this
 must go
##
hello world
##and this one
too##
```

I want to remove all between **##**, including multi lines, so I am left  just with `hello world`

This removes only part that is on one line:

```
sed -i.bak 's/##.*##//g' myfile
```

How to remove multi line stuff too?

P.S Im on MAC

Comment: Probably perl solution will be simpler: `perl -0pe 's/##.*?##\R*//gs' file > newfile` ([demo](https://ideone.com/sCncMA)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hey your solution works the best - post your answer & I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: [Posted with explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433537/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `perl` to achieve what you want:

```
perl -0pe 's/##.*?##\R*//gs' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/sCncMA)

The `0` argument makes it possible to find matches across lines.

The pattern matches

- `##` - two `#` symbols
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars (even line break chars due to the `s` modifier) as few as possible
- `##` - two `#` symbols
- `\R*` - any 0+ line break sequences.

Answer (score 1):

It should be very easy task for `awk`(in case you are ok with it). Could you please try following, will add explanation shortly too.

```
awk '/^##.*##$/{next} /^##$/{flag="";next} /^##/ && !/##$/{flag=1} flag{next} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/^##.*##$/{
  next
}
/^##$/{
  flag=""
  next
}
/^##/ && !/##$/{
  flag=1
}
flag{
  next
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this:

```
sed -n '/^##/ { :1 ; /##$/ { d } ; n ; b 1 } ; p' myfile
```

Wise men read this excellent tutorial: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51)

The test:

```
sed -n '/^##/ { :1 ; /##$/ { d } ; n ; b 1 } ; p' myfile

hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/##[^#]*\(#[^#][^#]*\)*##\n\?//g' file
```

The `-z` option allows the whole of the file to be slurped into sed's pattern space. The regexp match is in three parts. The first part matches `##` followed by zero or more non-`#`'s. The second part matches a zero or more group of characters consisting of a single `#` followed by a non-`#` followed by zero or more non-`#`'s. The third part matches `##` and a possible newline. This regexp removes such matches globally throughout the file.

This can by shortened slightly by using the `-r` option to sweeten the final offering to:

```
sed -rz 's/##[^#]*(#[^#]+)*##\n?//g' file
```

If the version of sed does not offer either options, then another solution is:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/##[^#]*\(#[^#][^#]*\)*##\n\?//g' file
```

It should by noted, that in the example above, all `##`'s either start or end at the beginning or end of a line and so the solution below might also fit the bill:

```
sed 's/^##/,/##$/d' file
```