# How can I remove multiline Comment From a Code using Sed and Regex

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to remove a multiline comment and single line comment from a file using `sed`. My file looks like:

```
<#
Comment Block Data
Comment Block Data
#>
If (a= Example)
#
Comment Data
#
If (b= Example)
```

I want the following result.

```
If (a= Example)
If (b= Example)
```

I have successfully removed the # comments but I am unable to remove <# #> comments from the file. Is there a way around to remove all together using regex?

It is a PowerShell script.

To remove `'#'` lines I used the following regex: `"/^[[:blank:]]*#/d;s/#.*//"`

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. You mentioned you were successfully able to remove the `#` comments but not the other ones, how did you do this. Can you [edit] your question and add this information to the question?

Comment: Does your text contain `<#\n<#\n#>` that is multiple opening `<#` within a single multi-line comment? If so than regular expressions are probably not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Also, what is a single line comment? and which language is this?

Comment: Already answered, read and adapt what is in this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53432910/remove-everything-between-specified-characters-including-multi-lines/53433165#53433165

Answer (score 0):

This sed oneliner works for the example you gave:

```
 sed '/^<#/,/^#>/d;/^#$/,/^#$/d' file
```

Well, there could be many possibilities to break the line above, like, not paired `<# or #` and so on. So you should double check your source files after you executed the line.

You can add `-i` (gnu sed) to save the changes in your file.

Comment: Above one-liner is not working. Would it be possible for you to give me a solution of multiline comment only? 

<#
    Comment Data
    Comment Data
#>

It is PowerShell script.

Comment: @user2670674 **This sed oneliner works for the example you gave**

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann sed supports `/pat1/,/pat2/` as range address

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann yes they are same. you are miss nothing. The patterns (regex) are same, but this doesn't mean they will indicate the same address. also `/^#$/d` is not correct. if you took a look OP's example and expected output, you will find the `Comment Data` line sits between two `#` lines.